# Unable to use convert strings into integers for a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I am trying to create a golf calculator in which I enter two strings (par_string,score_string). For each item in par_string and score_string, I subtract the score_string item from the par_string item.

I have tried turning the strings into integers but it still doesn't work.

```
#score_string-par_string
def golf_score_calculator(par_string, score_string):
    new_str = ""
    par = int(par_string,10)
    score = int(score_string,10)
    for i in str(par):
        for i in str(score):
            new_str += score_string[i]-par_string[i]
    return new_str
print(golf_score_calculator("12","13"))
```

What should happen is that each time a value is subtracted, it adds on to new_str.

Comment: `for i in str(par):` is like `for i in str(12):` What are you trying to do? What is your desired output?

Comment: do you really need `for` loops for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is bacause you are using the same index for two nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is odd you are using strings instead of lists of ints but if you have two strings and you want the difference, simply doing

```
def golf_score_calculator(par_string, score_string):
    return str(int(par_string) - int(score_string))
```

should be what you want.